# Calculate sum of largest sequence of decreasing odd ints

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, array

I wrote a method that finds the maximum sum of consecutive decreasing sequence of odd integers.

For example: if sequence is 13 9 7 12 13 15 13, then sum is 29 (13 + 9 + 7).

I don't think it's as good as it could be, because the same code is repeated multiple times.

```
static int SumOfLargestSequence(int[] array)
        {
            int sumMax = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (array[i] % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        sum += array[i];

                        if (sumMax < sum)
                        {
                            sumMax = sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (sum != 0)
                        {
                            if (array[i - 1] > array[i])
                            {
                                sum += array[i];

                                if (sumMax < sum)
                                {
                                    sumMax = sum;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sum += array[i];

                            if (sumMax < sum)
                            {
                                sumMax = sum;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return sumMax;
        }
```

Comment: Consider *why* you check for `i != 0` before `array[i - 1] > array[i]`.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the specification: For  
`13 9 7 43`,  
the sum of the longest consecutive decreasing sequence is 29, while the largest sum of any consecutive decreasing sequence is 43.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the biggest problem with your code is that there are too many (unnecessary) branches inside the loop, which ruins the legibility of your code.

First let me share with you my refactored version:

```
static int SumOfLargestSequence(int[] array)
{
    int sum = array[0] % 2 == 1 ? array[0] : 0;
    int sumMax = sum;

    for (int idx = 1; idx < array.Length; idx++)
    {
        if (array[idx] % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (sum == 0 || array[idx - 1] > array[idx])
        {
            sum += array[idx];
            sumMax = sumMax < sum ? sum : sumMax;
        }
    }

    return sumMax;
}
```

Now let's see the refactoring work step-by-step.

#### The first element

```
if (i == 0)
{
    if (array[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        sum += array[i];

        if (sumMax < sum)
        {
            sumMax = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

- Performing this branching in every iteration is pointless.

  - Rather start the loop from 1 (`for (int idx = 1; idx < array.Length; idx++)`).
  - And assign the initial values at variable declarations.

```
int sum = array[0] % 2 == 1 ? array[0] : 0;
int sumMax = sum;
```

#### The even case

```
if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
{
    sum = 0;
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

- If number is even then reset the `sum` and move on.

  - With the `continue` statement you don't need the `else` block.

```
if (array[idx] % 2 == 0)
{
    sum = 0;
    continue;
}

...
```

#### The descending order and the after reset cases

```
if (sum != 0)
{
    if (array[i - 1] > array[i])
    {
        sum += array[i];

        if (sumMax < sum)
        {
            sumMax = sum;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    sum += array[i];

    if (sumMax < sum)
    {
        sumMax = sum;
    }
}
```

- You want to execute the exact same steps under two different circumstances.

  - Combine your conditions to have a single branch.
  - Also use ternary conditional operator to calculate the value of `sumMax`.

```
if (sum == 0 || array[idx - 1] > array[idx])
{
    sum += array[idx];
    sumMax = sumMax < sum ? sum : sumMax;
}
```

---

As it was mentioned by others your requirements are a bit vague so try to spend some time to better understand the problem space and have requirements for suboptimal conditions as well.

Comment: See [John's comment](/a/280574?#comment-556030) on my answer for some thoughts on the return value for e.g. `{ -1 }`.  There's an argument that the empty subsequence has a sum of zero, which might be the correct return value here.  As you say in your final comment, it's important to find what result is expected!

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight, as I have written in the last line of my answer the OP's implementation considers only optimal circumstances (all values are positive and there are at least one item in the passed collection). All other cases are unhandled, so (s)he has to gather the requirements to be able to properly handle suboptimal cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't one of my languages, but I think I can follow the logic (that's good - the algorithm is evidently clear enough not to need any comments).

Firstly, a possible bug: if all the input values are negative, we claim that the result is `0`, because `sumMax` is initialised to `0`.  We should start with the *most negative* integer value - or better, use and return an *optional* int, since it's possible the input array doesn't contain any negative values.  But you need to confirm with the customer what result is expected in these cases - there's also an argument that an empty subsequence has a sum of zero, in which case this code is correct.  Either way, I recommend having a clarificatory comment there.

You haven't shown the unit tests for this code, but I recommend you add tests for the cases I've just described before starting to refactor.  In fact, when writing tests, I would normally start with empty array as input, as that's usually the easiest case to get passing!

We don't need to test against `sumMax` for each element within a descending sequence - we reach a maximum sum when we add the last positive value in the subsequence.

Perhaps a fundamental rethink of the algorithm could help simplify this code.  At present, we examine each element to see whether it terminates a descending sequence of odd numbers.  We could instead think of the problem in terms of *search*: first search for an odd number, then search from its successor for the end of the sequence (end of array, even number, not-less-than previous member, or a negative number¹).  We can then sum the values of that subsequence, advance past any negative numbers less than the new `sumMax`, then look for the next odd number to begin a new subsequence.

---

¹ A negative number should end the sequence, because including it will make the sum smaller, as will its more-negative successors.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug to return 0 when all input numbers are negative.  It would be consistent to take that as the sum of a zero-length (sub-)sequence, and therefore a valid result.  That would also justify returning 0 when all the array elements are even (and what otherwise should the function return in such cases?).

Comment: Good point @John.  I considered the empty optional to be the correct return, but thinking of it as a zero-length subsequence arguably makes more sense.  It's certainly a good case for properly negotiating the requirements with the customer!